# What is appBitsCpy() function in UE4 C++ Code?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm analyzing the Unreal Engine 4.21 network handshake packet and I found appBitsCpy() function.

I don't understand what this is, so please teach me what is this :D

BitReader.cpp

```
void appBitsCpy( uint8* Dest, int32 DestBit, uint8* Src, int32 SrcBit, int32 BitCount )
{
    ...

    // Main copier, uses byte sized shifting. Minimum size is 9 bits, so at least 2 reads and 2 writes.
    uint32 DestIndex        = DestBit/8;
    uint32 FirstSrcMask  = 0xFF << ( DestBit & 7);  
    uint32 LastDest     = ( DestBit+BitCount )/8; 
    uint32 LastSrcMask   = 0xFF << ((DestBit + BitCount) & 7); 
    uint32 SrcIndex     = SrcBit/8;
    uint32 LastSrc      = ( SrcBit+BitCount )/8;  
    int32   ShiftCount    = (DestBit & 7) - (SrcBit & 7); 
    int32   DestLoop      = LastDest-DestIndex; 
    int32   SrcLoop       = LastSrc -SrcIndex;  
    uint32 FullLoop;
    uint32 BitAccu;

    // Lead-in needs to read 1 or 2 source bytes depending on alignment.
    if( ShiftCount>=0 )
    {
        FullLoop  = FMath::Max(DestLoop, SrcLoop);  
        BitAccu   = Src[SrcIndex] << ShiftCount; 
        ShiftCount += 8; //prepare for the inner loop.
    }
    else
    {
        ShiftCount +=8; // turn shifts -7..-1 into +1..+7
        FullLoop  = FMath::Max(DestLoop, SrcLoop-1);  
        BitAccu   = Src[SrcIndex] << ShiftCount; 
        SrcIndex++;     
        ShiftCount += 8; // Prepare for inner loop.  
        BitAccu = ( ( (uint32)Src[SrcIndex] << ShiftCount ) + (BitAccu)) >> 8; 
    }

    // Lead-in - first copy.
    Dest[DestIndex] = (uint8) (( BitAccu & FirstSrcMask) | ( Dest[DestIndex] &  ~FirstSrcMask ) );
    SrcIndex++;
    DestIndex++;

    // Fast inner loop. 
    for(; FullLoop>1; FullLoop--) 
    {   // ShiftCount ranges from 8 to 15 - all reads are relevant.
        BitAccu = (( (uint32)Src[SrcIndex] << ShiftCount ) + (BitAccu)) >> 8; // Copy in the new, discard the old.
        SrcIndex++;
        Dest[DestIndex] = (uint8) BitAccu;  // Copy low 8 bits.
        DestIndex++;        
    }

    // Lead-out. 
    if( LastSrcMask != 0xFF) 
    {
        if ((uint32)(SrcBit+BitCount-1)/8 == SrcIndex ) // Last legal byte ?
        {
            BitAccu = ( ( (uint32)Src[SrcIndex] << ShiftCount ) + (BitAccu)) >> 8; 
        }
        else
        {
            BitAccu = BitAccu >> 8; 
        }       

        Dest[DestIndex] = (uint8)( ( Dest[DestIndex] & LastSrcMask ) | (BitAccu & ~LastSrcMask) );          
    }   
}
```

So I want know this

1. What is this?
2. Why shake the bit?
3. Will I benefit from using this?

Please help me!

Comment: Have you read [this](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Serialization/appBitsCpy/index.html)?

Comment: yes, i read it but can't understand code :(

Comment: Okay, as I don't have much experience with Unreal I can't exactly help you. I just wanted to ask to see if I could help out.

Comment: @Kenzoid In fairness to the op, the unreal documentation is uh... spotty. Most of the code documentation is generated and often less helpful than than the source code interface.